# How to display multiple time zones on an android wear watch face

Tags: android, watch-face-api

I have built a watch face that tells time in two different ways. The watch face has 12hr format for the current time zone and 24hr format for GMT. By default the watch face only displays the current time zone which means my hour hand for the GMT is really only indicating the time in the current time zone in 24hr format. How do I make the watch display multiple time zones simultaneously?

Answer (score 0):

You can create 2 Calendar objects with different time zones and then use this objects:

```
Calendar germanyTime = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getDefault());//your timezone
Calendar germanyTime = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+0"));
```

Comment: thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Where in my code should it be applied?

Comment: this code demonstrates the main idea, that you can hold 2 independent calendar objects and get time from different timezones

Comment: I understand but Im no master programmer so its kinda foreign to me. lol

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you an example on how I managed to automatically get the system's time format:

```
// variables
boolean is24Hour = false;
DateFormat df;
Calendar cal;

// get time format
is24Hour = df.is24HourFormat(context);

...

@Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas, Rect bounds) {
    // always get a new instance in your onDraw()
        cal = Calendar.getInstance();

    // get the hours
       if (is24Hour) {
            format = new SimpleDateFormat("H");
            return Integer.valueOf(format.format(cal.getTime()));
        } else {
            format = new SimpleDateFormat("h");
            return (Integer.valueOf(format.format(cal.getTime()));
        }
     }
```